# Distinct returning duplicates with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, geolocation

im developing an application in android for showing bus routes from my hometown, i have problems
with a query, i have two tables in my app as shown below:

table INFORMATION

```
ID | NAME     | DIRECTION
--------------------------
 1 | BUS 1    | departure
 2 | BUS 1    | return
 3 | BUS 2    | departure
 4 | BUS 2    | return
 5 | BUS 3    | departure
 6 | BUS 3    | return
```

table COORDINATES

```
ID | INFORMATION_ID |     LAT   |     LON       |
-------------------------------------------------
 1 |    1           | 19.171184 | -96.174029    |
 2 |    1           | 19.171021 | -96.173991    |
 3 |    1           | 19.171002 | -96.173979    |
 5 |    2           | 19.193244 | -96.138732    |
 6 |    2           | 19.193368 | -96.138957    |
 7 |    2           | 19.193332 | -96.138741    |
```

I'm trying to show nearby bus routes within 500 m range, and i'm actually able to do it with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME,
((example.lat  - COORDINATES.LAT) * (example.lat - COORDINATES.LAT) + (example.lon - COORDINATES.LON) * (example.lon - COORDINATES.LON)) AS DISTANCE  
FROM COORDINATES
INNER JOIN INFORMATION
ON COORDINATES.INFORMATION_ID=INFORMATION.ID 
WHERE DISTANCE < 0.000023544  //supposedly 500 m, im not sure
ORDER BY DISTANCE
```

But the problem is that i have repeated values in the NAME field because i have several latlon points from the bus routes that are within the range,
i just need to return the minimun distance with the corresponding name like this:

```
ID | NAME     | DISTANCE
---------------------
 1 | BUS 1    | 1.349834...
 3 | BUS 2    | 1.367033...
```

I'll aprecciate any guidance towards resolving this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps to get the shortest distance out.

```
SELECT NAME, MIN(DISTANCE) FROM
(
SELECT NAME, 
((19.171150  - COORDINATES.LAT) * (19.171184 - COORDINATES.LAT) + 
 (-96.173990 - COORDINATES.LON) * (-96.173990 - COORDINATES.LON)) AS DISTANCE  
FROM COORDINATES
INNER JOIN INFORMATION
ON COORDINATES.INFORMATION_ID=INFORMATION.ID 
WHERE DISTANCE < 0.000023544
) 
GROUP BY NAME
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2e1ea/4

Comment: thaks, but the query only returns the min distance from one bus, i need the min distance from all the buses within the range. [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrsxooh7akhuiiy/Screenshot_2015-10-14_20-19-11.png?dl=0)

Comment: i did misunderstood. I am updating the answer, give me a few mins.. thanks.